# How to detect unexpected copy in move expected case

Tags: lambda, copy, c++14, move, mutable

When I use lambda expression, sometimes I do move capture copyable and movable object. In my following example, the object is `t` and its type is `tracer`. In the lambda expression, I want to move `t` again to other function `f()`. `f()`'s parameter is passed by value because I want to support both copy and move for `f()`.

The first part of the `main()` I call `f(std::move(t))` but it is not moved but copied because `t` is captured as const variable. The second part of the `main()` function, I added to `mutable` to the lambda expression. It works as I expected.

I often forget adding `mutable` to the lambda expression. If `t` is move only type, the first case makes compile error. I can easy to notice the problem. But if `t` is copyable and movable, it is difficult for me to notice unexpected copy. I want to check that case.

Is there any good way to do that?

```
#include <iostream>

struct tracer {
    tracer() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~tracer() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << this << std::endl;
    }
    tracer(tracer const& other) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << this << " <- " << &other << std::endl;
    }
    tracer(tracer&& other) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << this << " <- " << &other << std::endl;
    }
    tracer& operator=(tracer const& other) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << this << " <- " << &other << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    tracer& operator=(tracer&& other) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << this << " <- " << &other << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

void f(tracer) {
}

int main() {
    {
        tracer t;
        // move assign capture
        [t = std::move(t)] { // forget write mutable
            f(std::move(t)); // I expect move but copy due to lack of mutable
        }();
    }
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    {
        tracer t;
        // move assign capture
        [t = std::move(t)] () mutable {
            f(std::move(t)); // Moved as I expected
        }();
    }
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vphaVOXYhN0sr42o

Comment: If your test cases are small enough you can temporarily `=delete` the copy construtor, to ensure you are really moving the object.

Comment: @alfC thank you for the comment. It works. But my actual code is big and sometimes I really want to copy `trace t1; trace t2 = t1`. `=delete` approach make compile errors such place. It is noisy to find the target part of problem.

Comment: Sure, I understand, that is why I said that the test code must be small (and not involving any actual copy) for testing this. Having said that, test code should be small anyway.

Comment: Another method is to make `f` only accept r-values. `f(tracer&&)`, again in test small enough so that only this kind of calls to `f` are performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I come up with a solution. I wrote the following wrapper for `std::move()`.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_reference_t<T>&&
only_move(T&& t) {
    static_assert(!std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, "T is const. Fallback to copy.");
    return std::move(t);
}
```

And I replaced `std::move()` with `only_move()` as follows:

```
int main() {
    {
        tracer t;
        // move assign capture
        [t = only_move(t)] { // got static assertion failed *1
            f(only_move(t)); // I expect move but copy due to lack of mutable
        }();
    }
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    {
        tracer t;
        // move assign capture
        [t = only_move(t)] () mutable {
            f(only_move(t)); // Moved as I expected
        }();
    }
}
```

Then I got static assertion failed message only if I forgot `mutable`.

*1 error: static_assert failed due to requirement '!std::is_const_v' "T is const. Fallback to copy.

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3HlrAab0IAUYQON8